# The following package has umet dependencies:

Tags: kali-linux, gnuplot

I did `apt-get dist-upgrade` and got this error while installing.

```
The following package has umet dependencies:
 gnuplot-qt : Depends: gnuiplot-data (=5.0.7+dfsg1-1) but it is not installed
E: Umet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no package (or specify a solution).
```

I tried `apt --fix-broken install` and i got this error

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/archives/gnuplot-data_5.0.7+dfsg1-1_all.deb (--unpack)
:
   trying to overwrite '/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/gnuplot/gnuplot-lua-tikz-common.tex', which is also in package gnuplot-tex 4.6.6-3
```

So,i tried to reboot and my Linux couldn't boot up ever since.

i use the recovery mode to try and run `apt-get update` but i got another error

```
Err:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling Inrelease
 Could not resolve 'http.kali.org'
```

Please i really need help.

Comment: Welcome to SU , Are you using Debian or Kali-linux? what is the output of `uname -a` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` ?

Comment: i'm using kali-linux

Comment: the sources.list is correct